# Comparing two dates in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to compare two dates and time values in PHP. One date is coming from MySQL, and second one is the current date. I want to run some code when both dates are the same. I tried the code below, but condition satisfies any time which is wrong.

```
$current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i');
$send_date = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($row['send_date'])); // suppose $row['send_date']'s value is '2016-10-17 15:00'
if($current_datetime == $send_date){
    //I want to run some code here
}else{
}
```

What is wrong with the code? I also tried to covert both dates with `strtotime()` before comparing, but it gave me the same issue. The above condition satisfies any time even if both dates are different.

Comment: How precisely do you want to compare them? Up to hours?

Comment: No, its not duplicate question, I read that question but did not get answer what I want, that is why I asked new one.

Comment: I want to compare date and time(hours and minutes). I don't want to compare seconds.

Comment: Also you compare like that:

$var =  $row['send_date'];

if((time()-(60*60*24)) == strtotime($var)){ ... }

Comment: What is your output of `$row['send_date']`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
$current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i');
$send_date = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($row['send_date'])); // suppose $row['send_date']'s value is '2016-10-17 15:00'
if(strtotime($current_datetime) == strtotime($send_date)){
    //I want to run some code here
}else{
}
```

Hope it helps !!!!

Comment: What you have changed?. Explain properly.

Comment: @AHJeebon : i did convert the dates in to strtotime format because that's the right way to compare the date values.

Comment: @KaushaThakkar : Yes, this code runs fine for me. Thanks

Comment: @KetanLathiya Thanks !! can you please give it a green tick :)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to fetch the [Unix timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) from MySQL, then operate on the numbers:

```
$row = get_db_row("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(send_date) AS send_date_ts
  FROM table WHERE $condition");
$hours = (int) ($row['send_date_ts'] / 3600);
$current_hours = (int) (time() / 3600);
if ($hours == $current_hours) {
  // current hour
}
```

Timestamps are convenient because:

- there is no need to take the format into account;
- operations on numbers are usually faster;
- the code looks cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. On my server is working just great I've got something else because they aren't equal. Date which I receive from database is type `datetime` format `2015-04-13 09:03:49`

```
<?php
     $current_datetime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));
     $send_date = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($row['send_date'])); // suppose $row['send_date']'s value is '2016-10-17 15:00'
     if($current_datetime == $send_date){
         //I want to run some code here
         echo 'something';
     }else{ 
         echo 'something else';
     }
```

Output:

```
echo $current_datetime . '<br/>';
2016-10-17 09:19

echo $send_date .'<br/>';    
2015-04-13 09:03

// result
something else
```

Comment: You are comparing a string to an integer, can't work. strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i')) is never equal to date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($row['send_date'])).